# What are the differences between jsCoq and the versions of Coq that can be downloaded?

Tags: coq

I found a site where I can use Coq in my browser: [jsCoq Interactive Online System](https://coq.vercel.app/). Are there any major differences between the experience I'm getting on this site and the downloadable version(s)?

Comment: For me it says "`Failed to start jsCoq worker`" when I open that page, so that would be one difference!

Answer (score 14):

jsCoq is based on the Coq source code (regularly updated to use newer Coq versions), compiled to Javascript (or WebAssembly) to run in the browser using [js_of_ocaml](https://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/latest/manual/overview). The main differences with running Coq on the desktop is that jsCoq is slower and that the fast reduction machines (`vm_compute` and `native_compute`) are disabled. It also comes with a set of bundled libraries, which is similar in spirit to the [Coq Platform](https://github.com/coq/platform), but different in terms of library choice and version numbers. Obviously, the GUI is also (very slightly) different to the various editors with Coq support that are out there.

jsCoq is developed at: https://github.com/jscoq/jscoq