# WLOG reasoning and Proof Assistants

Tags: program-extraction, equivalence-relation, program-correctness, without-loss-of-generality

The possibility of using proof assistants in combinatorics has been mentioned [here](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/43/proof-assistants-for-beginners-a-comparison) and in more detail [here](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/190/162).  I'm interested in automating that part of some discrete problems which *reduces* the search space "without loss of generality" by exploiting various symmetries.

I'll mention for context a couple of problems I'm interested in:

(1) Counting (doubly) diagonal [latin squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square) invites reduction of a search space by [the centralizer of a specific permutation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117359/centralizer-of-a-specific-permutation). A latin square of size $n\times n$ has the numbers $1,2,\ldots,n$ in each row and each column without repetition.  Such a square is [doubly diagonal](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/eng-2017-0052/html?lang=en) iff the main diagonal and the anti-diagonal also have each $n$ distinct entries.  For example:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 4 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
3 & 2 & 4 & 1 \\
\hline
4 & 1 & 3 & 2 \\
\hline
2 & 3 & 1 & 4 \\
\hline \end{array} \;\text{ and }\;
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
5 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
4 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
\hline
2 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 3 \\
\hline
3 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 4 \\
\hline \end{array}
$$

(2) An [absorbing Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain) might be naively formulated using many equivalent states and transitions, and this invites for some purposes (e.g. expected steps until an absorbing state is reached) pruning the search space by [symmetries of states](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909313/coupon-collector-prob-variation).

My intuition is that proving "without loss of generality" cases is similar to proving program correctness.  Prolog code has often helped me with checking that "all bases are covered," but I experience a certain amount of frustration with reinventing the wheel because of the weak(!) datatyping in Prolog.  So I'd be interested if [setoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setoid) or some other construction would provide rigorous analysis of cases.

Comment: @GuyCoder:  When I searched a few years ago, I found a mention and a handful of counts in a book chapter of an "encyclopedia" on combinatorics.  A more recent paper is "Enumerating Diagonal Latin Squares
of Order Up to 9" by [Kochemazov and Zaikin (2020)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL23/Zaikin/zaikin3.pdf).  Enumerating means listing them out, not merely counting them.  They contributed the counts [OEIS A274806](https://oeis.org/A274806).

Comment: @GuyCoder:  I left a brief comment there, about symmetries that help to count or list solutions for $n=4$.  Larger orders involve deeper symmetries described in [Centralizer of a specific permutation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117359/centralizer-of-a-specific-permutation).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

John Harrison had [a nice paper](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejrh13/papers/wlog.pdf) about “wlog” reasoning and the logical requirements behind it.  The paper talks about various ways in which these can be automated.  This is in HOL Light, and I know there is an analogous tactic in HOL4. Given how foundationally simple HOL is, I expect  the logic works in other systems too.

Comment: Thanks, this is very on point.