Using Lean or Coq
How do Coq and Lean compare for doing actual proofs. Have been perusing my intention of using Lean rather than Coq.
A am interested in proving fourier and wavelet transform theorems.   Coq is very complicated and hard to learn.  I suspect that Lean is easier to use.  But I also suspect that
Coq is more powerful, and is probably better for dealing with complicated mathematics.
I think that Coq could have long longevity; whereas with microsoft, things could eventually die.

https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/q/43/32 maybe relevant

These two systems have similar core, so no need to concern about the powerfulness. The main difference imo is the ecosystem

Let me know if you think this should not be considered duplicate!

Lean isn’t really a Microsoft product in the sense you are thinking of.  It is open source, its main author is now at Amazon, and it’s governed by the Lean FRO which is independent of a specific company.
